# checking regex on keypress for phonenumber

Tags: jquery, typescript

its regex for phone number but its work  for each character  not string"091222222222"

```
            $('#SWF_Membership_SignUpPanel0_MobileNumber').bind('keypress', function (event) {
            var regex = new RegExp('09([0-9])-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}');
            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                Q.notifyWarning("wrong Phone number!");

                return false;
            }
          
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: Which phone numbers are you actually trying to validate here?

Comment: for example   09120383623